# How do I enable Error Reporting in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have made a contact form but upon submitting it I get the error: Oops, an error occurred! Code: 201905310232036dfcc153.

I would like to get more information so I can start debugging. So my question is: How do I enable error reporting in TYPO3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to add this line in your TypoScript

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

After setting to `0`, you will see detailed errors in frontend when an exception 
is thrown.
To reset it, simply delete the lin or set to `1`.

here is a blog post from me about it (in German): https://www.naderio.de/oops-an-error-occurred-komplette-fehlermeldung-anzeigen/

Answer (score 3):

In the directory `typo3temp/var/logs/` there should be a file named `typo3_somehash.log`. Search this file for the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Install Tool and configure SYS|displayErrors = 1

This enables the debug exception handler and you will get a stacktrace instead oops an error occurred.

You can also write it directly in your typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php or typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][SYS]['displayErrors'] = 1;
```

See also: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Configuration/Index.html

Comment: I checked and in LocalConfiguration.php the displayErrors global is already set to 1. I also turned on debug mode in the configuration presets. Yet I am still not getting a more detailed error description. How is that possible?