# Typo3 extbase : How can i catch an exception?

Tags: exception, typo3, extbase

I'm currently develloping an extension in Typo3 10.4 and I can't working out a problem

I'm using some external libs for mailing or payments which sometimes throw exceptions.

My problem is that when this is happening i got an OOPS error even if I try to catch the exception

for exemple :

```
//CODE BEFORE
try{
  //SOME CODE WHO SENDS EMAIL AND SOMETIMES THROW EXCEPTION
  //BECAUSE THE CONNECTION FAILED
}catch(Exception $e){
  //DO SOMETHING
}
//CODE AFTER
```

And it's a pretty annoying problem because some DB actions are not completed then

I'm sure there is a way to deal with the exception without stopping all the script but i don't know how...

Can someone help plz?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct and TYPO3 shouldn't interfere. Thus, there seems to be another issue, so a few things to consider here:

Please keep in mind that your TYPO3 extension code is namespaced, if you really `catch(Exception $e)` it means \Your\Namespace\Exception - you probably want  `catch(\Exception $e)`.

That said, additionally configure a way to show the exception stack trace instead of "Oops" as output (the more simple approach, see e.g. [How do I enable Error Reporting in TYPO3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715965/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-typo3)) or connect a remote debugger like xdebug (more advanced) in order to see more than the Oops and get the real cause of the error and how it propagates.

If you aren't able to change the actual TYPO3 system you work on for reasons, an alternative could be to use an easy to set up local dev system like DDEV. This offers a simplified way to create a local TYPO3 instance, see e.g. [the TYPO3 blog article](https://typo3.com/blog/tutorial-get-a-local-typo3-v10-installation-with-no-effort%5D)

Comment: You're right I have to catch \Exception for it to work! I knew i was missing something stupid ^^ Thanks a lot